# How to create list without left and right border HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to create a list using Kendo mobile list view which is as below:

```
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   1        |    2   |    3   |        4
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   1        |    2   |    3   |        4
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   1        |    2   |    3   |        4
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
   1        |    2   |    3   |        4
   +--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Basically list without left and right border.
Currently I am using `div` to display this list but problem is that I am not able remove left and right border and also in between (divider lines) I see double border as left and right 1px boarder together makes it 2px.

Also the element in first column are left aligned and element in last column are aligned to right, and rest in center.

How we can implement thin using HTML and CSS.

Comment: Do you have any code yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:first-child`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp) and `:last-child` pseudo selector to style the first and last row seperately.

For the double border you can use [`border-collapse: collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)

Answer (score 0):

without your code,  we'll do just with divs.

the idea is to do with most simple selector we can use instead dispatching class or id so no need to touch your script:

> combinator https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators
>
> structural pseudo class https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos which includes https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo & https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo

```
body>div {
}
:first-child {
}
:last-child {
}
div + div {
}
```

```css
body {
  display: table;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border-top: solid 1px;
}
div {
  border-bottom: solid 1px;
}
body>div {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
}
div div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
}
div div:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
div div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
div div + div {
  border-left: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

any numbers of row or cols will do

```css
body {
  display: table;
  border-top: solid;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
div {
  border-bottom: solid;
}
body>div {
  display: table-row;
  text-align: center;
}
div div {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50px;
}
div div:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
div div:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
div div + div {
  border-left: solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, this is exactly I am looking for, but thing is I am using kendo list view and kendo template for displaying my list, and in my code I only have `<div><div>My Data</div></div>` in the template and i need to build listing using this. this template is repeated/used for creating every row and column of the table. so problem is last_child and first_child is not working in this case.

Comment: Could you present a fiddle of your problem?

Comment: @A_user as Aides said, without your code, or what you tried so far, no way to go further helping you. I gave the hints for the styling and the way to select your elements.There is nothing more i can do for you from what your question tells